# How to get a form to submit twice using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to submit a form to a new window and then submit slightly altered values to the same form in the original window. I have the following function to do that.

```
//Now lets create the page making function!
function createInternetPage() {

//Start by checking to see if the internet page has been requested. 
req_int = document.getElementById("marterial_internet").checked;

    if (req_int == true){
        //If it has, create the internet page.
//Send the completed form to submit in a new window, creating the broadcast page. 
document.getElementById("new_material").setAttribute("target","_blank");
document.forms["new_material"].submit();

//Add "(Internet)" to the current form title
var title = document.getElementById("material_title").value;
var title_new = title + " (Internet)";
title = document.getElementById("material_title").value = title_new;

//Then submit the form on the existing window to make the internet page. 
document.getElementById("new_material").setAttribute("target","_self");
document.forms["new_material"].submit();
        }

        //If it has not been requested then just submit the normal form. 
        else {
            //alert("NOT Checked");
            document.getElementById("new_material").setAttribute("target","_self");
            document.forms["new_material"].submit();
        }

}
```

Everything work great EXCEPT that the form on the original window never gets submitted. It changes the material_title value to add " (Internet)" after it but doesn't submit the form.

Any ideas why this is and a work around to get this working?

**EDIT:** 
When adding a setTimeout delay, see below, the same thing is happening. Everything runs except for the last form submit.

```
function delay() {
    //Send the completed form to submit in a new window, creating the broadcast page. 
document.getElementById("new_material").setAttribute("target","_blank");
document.forms["new_material"].submit();

}
function delay2(){
    var title = document.getElementById("material_title").value;
var title_new = title + " (Internet)";
title = document.getElementById("material_title").value = title_new;

//Then submit the form on the existing window to make the internet page. 
document.getElementById("new_material").setAttribute("target","_self");
document.forms["new_material"].submit();
}

//Now lets create the page making function!
function createInternetPage() {

//Start by checking to see if the internet page has been requested. 
req_int = document.getElementById("marterial_internet").checked;

    if (req_int == true){
        //If it has, create the internet page.
delay()
//Add "(Internet)" to the current form title
setTimeout('delay2()',10000);
        }

        //If it has not been requested then just submit the normal form. 
        else {
            //alert("NOT Checked");
            document.getElementById("new_material").setAttribute("target","_self");
            document.forms["new_material"].submit();
        }

}
```

Comment: This is because the navigation get's cancelled right after it starts. Try a set timeout..

Answer (score 0):

You do not give enough time for the form to do the actions. You need to break up the requests.   Use a setTimeout to do the second action.

If you are submitting to the same domain, you can always use Ajax to make the first submission and not open up a new window.

Better, is have the server handle the requests and make a second submission.

Comment: Once the form has been submitted it returns a second form where more details can be entered. That's why I need both windows to be opened.

Comment: Well use a setTimeout to do the second submission so the first one has time to process.

Comment: Adding a setTimeout seems to work for changing the title field (it delays it) but just like before, it doesn't submit the form again.